# Intersection of subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: vector-spaces

If there are subspaces $U$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $4$-dim real vector space, and their dimensions are $2$ and $3$ respectively, is it impossible for their intersection to be of dimension $0$?

I think the geometrical interpretation is that the intersection of a line and $3$d space cannot be a point, hence the answer is zero. Can you confirm this hypothesis and even generalize it to all dimensions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dim (U+V)=\dim (U)+\dim (U)-\dim (U\cap V).$

Since  $\dim(\Bbb R^4)=4$ and $U+V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$,  $\dim (U\cap V)=0$ will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: The correct formula says $U+V$, not $U\cup V$. The later is not even a vector space in general.

Comment: @stressedout It was a typo. Is it fine now?

Comment: I noticed it was a typo, I just wanted you to fix it because it could've misled the OP. Yup. It's fine now. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\dim(U\cap V)+\dim(U+V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)$$